# Are my answers correct? (Graphs; paths; path lengths; circuits)

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image: question]

**My answers**

a) Yes, this forms a path.  This is a simple path.  The length of this path is 4.

b) Yes, this forms a path.  This is a circuit.  The length of this path is 4.

c) Yes, this forms a path.  This is a circuit.  The length of this path is 6.

d) Yes, this forms a path.  This is a circuit.  The length of this path is 7.

Comment: Note that a) is not simple, since vertex $b$ is repeated.

Comment: What are your definitions of "path", "simple", "circuit" and "length"?

Comment: @Adraino Can you explain what a simple path is then?

Comment: @dtldarek path is "a sequence of edges that begins at a vertex and travels from vertex to vertex along edges of a graph" - "a simple path is denoted by its vertex sequence" - "a circuit starts and ends at the same vertex" - "length is the number of edges"  and "A path or circuit is simple if it does not contain the same edge more than once
"

Comment: @adriano isn't a) simple because it does not contain the same edge more than once?

Comment: I think c) and d) are not paths as the directed edges $(d,b)$ and $(b,d)$ do not exist in the graph shown.

Comment: Wikipedia says that simple paths have no repeated vertices (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Different_types_of_paths).

Comment: @Daniel but because b can be reached from d, isn't it still a path?

Comment: @positiveimpact, no because you don't know which way is being taken to get from b to d.  Is it b,e,d or b,a,d?  There are multiple paths here which is why the list of vertices specifies the edges to be used to make the path.

Comment: Makes sense; thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your definitions:

1. path is a sequence of edges that begins at a vertex and travels from vertex to vertex along edges of a graph
2. "a circuit starts and ends at the same vertex"
3. "length is the number of edges"
4. "A path or circuit is simple if it does not contain the same edge more than once "

If I guess correctly the intention of the authors of this question, your answers to a) and b) are ok, however, c) and d) are not since $db$, $ea$ and $bd$ are not edges.

Also, please be aware (as @Adriano already pointed out) that usually "a simple path" means that you cannot enter vertex more than once or exit it more than once (in case of cycles you do both, but only once, i.e. one entry and one exit, so it's still ok). With such definition a) would not be a simple path (but according to your definition it is).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: My definitions may be wrong.  That's why I'm asking here.  Will you tell me whether or not my answers are correct based on YOUR definitions?

Comment: Also, I think c) and d) are paths because it is possible to reach b from d, and d from b across two edges.  Doesn't that satisfy my definition of a path?

Comment: That is why I don't like such questions, the authors weren't precise enough to tell, however, I guess that their intention was that those sequences of vertices should be the immediate neighbors in a path. In fact your graph is strongly connected, so with your interpretation _any_ sequence of vertices would be a path and as such, the question would be pointless (not to mention it would be rather hard to describe length, more like "possible lengths").